# Cannot update. Database or object is read only

Tags: sql, vba, dao, recordset

MS ACCESS DATABASE - VBA PROCEDURE.

I have an 'ETL' sort of process that has been running without ANY CHANGES to the code for months.  All of a sudden I am getting a frequent error "cannot update.  database or object is read only".

Given the research that I've done on this error, and given the fact that I have elaborate logging happening and I can pinpoint the EXACT place this happens, I thought I'd be able to figure out why.  Alas, I cannot.

Here, in the terms of my log file, is exactly when/where it happens:

> 8/5/2014 4:11:18 PM | For changedate 8/4/2014, number needing purged for CWHITE2 is 1
>
> 8/5/2014 4:11:18 PM |  identified 1 needing purged for CWHITE2, setting rsPurge accordingly
>
> 8/5/2014 4:11:18 PM | SQL for rsPurge is: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TBL_AUDIT_CLAIMS  WHERE [ANALYST_USERNAME]='CWHITE2' AND CHANGEDATE=#8/4/2014# AND LEN('' & [AUDITDATE])=0 ORDER BY [ID]
>
> 8/5/2014 4:11:18 PM | there are 1 records in rsPurge - looping to delete
>
> 8/5/2014 4:11:18 PM | deleting record from rsPurge
>
> 8/5/2014 4:11:18 PM Error occurred, being logged as: Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.

So, just like many other people who have received this error, I am--indeed--trying to DELETE from a DAO recordset. But it's the exact same SQL I've used to populate a recordset, then delete from it, for months.  What in the world would be the issue??  It's not a group by or totals query...

Lastly, to test things, I just pasted that EXACT sql in a regular query in the Access database, and when the one single record came up, I manually deleted it - no problem.

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Did you try to compact and repair you ms-access db? also, are there any updates to the database that are running in parallel, which may inter-lock one another?